# React Navigation 6 - Padding issue

Tags: react-native-navigation

I am working with @react-navigation/native 6 and using the headerLargeTitle option.

Depending on the screen size the padding of the title is changing. I could not find solution to adjust this through the documented APIs.

Any idea?[image]

```js
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
const PortfolioStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const PortfolioStackScreens = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <PortfolioStack.Navigator>
      <PortfolioStack.Screen
        name="Portfolio"
        component={PortfolioScreen}
        options={{
          headerLargeTitle: true,
          headerShadowVisible: false,
          headerLargeTitleShadowVisible: false,
        }}
      />
    </PortfolioStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Whether to enable header with large title which collapses to regular header on scroll.

For large title to collapse on scroll, the content of the screen should be wrapped in a scrollable view such as ScrollView or FlatList. If the scrollable area doesn't fill the screen, the large title won't collapse on scroll. You also need to specify contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" in your ScrollView, FlatList etc.

Only supported on iOS.
[Detail](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headerlargetitle)